# HTML5 Video with WebVTT Subtitle track: show part of line on delay

Tags: html5-video, webvtt

I'm trying to get this working in Chrome.

I have a page playing a HTML5 video, with a webvtt file for my subtitles. I'm trying to get one line to show up about a second after another line.....but keep the first line there.
Then make them disappear together.

Here's what I have:-

```
4
00:00:13.600 --> 00:00:16.400
Here is my first line.... 

5
00:00:14.600 --> 00:00:16.400
...and here is my second line.
```

For some reason, the first line is showing up at the bottom of the video....and the second line is then displayed above it.
That's not what I want.

I've also tried

```
4
00:00:13.600 --> 00:00:16.400
Here is my first line.... 
<00:00:14.600>...and here is my second line.
```

But both lines are being displayed together.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve, you should not use overlapping cues. Instead stop your cue #4 right before cue #5 and add both texts inside of cue #5:

```
4
00:00:13.600 --> 00:00:14.600
Here is my first line.... 

5
00:00:14.600 --> 00:00:16.400
Here is my first line.... 
...and here is my second line.
```

Comment: No, the OP has tryed something else. Cue #4 stops at 16.4 in his example. In my example it stops at 14.6. Additionally Cue #5 includes the text of Cue #4 in my example.

Comment: Wow.. I'm so so tired lol.  Sorry.  I'll remove my comment.  BTW, you can add some explanation as to what you're doing.  Your post was flagged for low quality.... so editing your post and putting in what you just told me will help to avoid this from happening again.

Comment: Well the answer is so simple and self-explanatory. I should would add noise, if I start to write some lonng explanations.

Comment: It almost works.... So when I try that I get the first line in Cue #4 show low on the video, then when Cue #5 comes in, the first line is higher, and the second line is at the position Cue #4 was in...... It's almost there...but can I position Cue #4 higher so it looks like line 1 is shown in the same place in both Cues?

Comment: There are ways to position webvtt. But I think, that this won't work 100% x-browser. See more about webvtt settings and regions.

Comment: I wasn't too concerned with being x-browser. For anyone that wanted to just get this working, add a line:90% on to the end of the timing.
90% may not be the right value...and it won't be x-browser...but this is how I managed to get subtitles being 'shifted' vertically.